# Excel formula within VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have quite a few cells that contain formula, then with VBA the outcome of this formula is the value for a variable, like so:

On sheet in cell `AS4`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((ROW($AE$4:$AE$997))*($AE$4:$AE$997<>"")))
```

and then in my VBA:

```
numRows = ws.Range("AS4").Value
```

However this is starting to get hard to keep track of which cell is feeding which variable, avoiding overwriting those cells on the sheet by accident, etc.

I need to be able to perform this calculation within VBA if I can, removing the need to have "calculation cells" on my sheet.

I have discovered there is a way to use formula with `WorksheetFunction`, but only found simple examples of this and cannot adapt it to my situation above.

```
numRows = WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(MAX((ROW($AE$4:$AE$997))*($AE$4:$AE$997<>"")))
```

Is not going to work...

Is there a way to do this, or am I better scrapping the idea of using formula and using a pure VBA method?

Comment: You could use the Evaluate function `numRows=Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((ROW($AE$4:$AE$997))*($AE$4:$AE$997<>"")))")`

Comment: Thanks, I get `Type Mismatch` though, I presume as the output of this is not the numerical value expected in `numRows` which is a `Long` variable. How can I get the value from this?

Comment: Sorry, you need to double up the inner quotes `numRows=Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((ROW($AE$4:$AE$997))*($AE$‌​4:$AE$997<>"""")))")`

Answer (score 0):

With help from SJR this was the answer:

```
numRows = [=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((ROW(Weights!$AE$4:$AE$997))*(Weights!$AE$4:$AE$997<>"""")))]
```

A bit more research taught me that `evaluate(" ")` can be just replaced with square brackets `[` and `]`. Although, if I had variables in the mix of this formula or the formula wasn't constant then I would have to use `Evaluate`.

I also needed to add the sheet name to the formula as this formula was no longer functioning within the sheet and `AE4:AE997` was no longer referring to the correct sheet.

Doubling up on quotes is also necessary as it is code and sees `"` differently to a formula on the sheet